# Facade a class without writing lots of boilerplate code?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter, .net-4.5, facade

Let's say I have a class from a 3rd-party, which is a data-model. It has perhaps 100 properties (some with public setters and getters, others with public getters but private setters). Let's call this class ContosoEmployeeModel

I want to facade this class with an interface (INavigationItem, which has Name and DBID properties) to allow it to be used in my application (it's a PowerShell provider, but that's not important right now). However, it also needs to be usable as a ContosoEmployeeModel.

My initial implementation looked like this:

```
public class ContosoEmployeeModel
{
    // Note this class is not under my control. I'm supplied
    // an instance of it that I have to work with.

    public DateTime EmployeeDateOfBirth { get; set; }
    // and 99 other properties.
}

public class FacadedEmployeeModel : ContosoEmployeeModel, INavigationItem
{
    private ContosoEmployeeModel model;
    public FacadedEmployeeModel(ContosoEmployeeModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    // INavigationItem properties
    string INavigationItem.Name { get; set;}

    int INavigationItem.DBID { get; set;}

    // ContosoEmployeeModel properties
    public DateTime EmployeeDateOfBirth
    {
        get { return this.model.EmployeeDateOfBirth; }
        set { this.model.EmployeeDateOfBirth = value; }
    }
    // And now write 99 more properties that look like this :-(
}
```

However, it's clear that this will involve writing a huge amount of boilerplate code to expose all the properties , and I'd rather avoid this if I can. I can T4 code-generate this code in a partial class, and will do if there aren't any better ideas, but I though I'd ask here to see if anyone had any better ideas using some [super](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) [wizzy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) of C# magic

Please note - the API I use to obtain the ContosoEmployeeModel can only return a ContosoEmployeeModel - I can't extend it to return a FacededEmployeeModel, so wrapping the model is the only solution I can think of - I'm happy to be corrected though :)

Comment: How about using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26.aspx

Comment: I'm confused - you inherit your facade class from `ContosoEmployeeModel` *AND* you have a `ContosoEmployeeModel` embedded in your facade via composition? Why?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Oooh - I'd never heard of that. This looks very promising - I'll try it out and post back

Comment: Maybe you could add an `object` property to `INavigationItem` which, when not `null`, is used instead of the `INavigationItem` when someone navigates to it?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to create the interface at all? If your class only has data and no operations what will you achieve by introducing an interface?

Comment: @Treb The API I use for saving/retrieving data takes a ContosoEmployeeModel. However, the application that manipulates the model (PowerShell in this case) takes an INavigationItem. Hope that's clear?

Comment: @Spender I don't control the ContosoEmployeeModel so can't refactor it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It looks like Auto-mapping won't help me here - my issue is that I'm too lazy to completely write the object in the first place. However, it's a good thing to know about, so cheers :)

Comment: @RB. Ah well, it was worth a shot. :)

Comment: @RB. : In which case, Resharper's delegating member feature is the droid you're looking for. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html ... perfect for generation of facades/proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other approach may be suitable for you is to use  AutoMapper to map base class to your facade here is sample code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var model = new Model { Count = 123, Date = DateTime.Now, Name = "Some name" };

            Mapper.CreateMap<Model, FacadeForModel>();
            var mappedObject = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<FacadeForModel>(model);

            Console.WriteLine(mappedObject);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Model
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            public int Count { get; set; }
        }

        interface INavigationItem
        {
            int Id { get; set; }

            string OtherProp { get; set; }
        }

        class FacadeForModel : Model, INavigationItem
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string OtherProp { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me - I need my FacadedEmployeeModel to have the same values for all 100 properties as the ContosoEmployeeModel.

Comment: What are you using the FacadedEmployeeModel for?

Comment: From an API I retrieve a Contoso model. However, I need to manipulate this as an INavigationItem. Therefore, the facade will turn a Contoso model into an INavigationItem.

Comment: Using the AutoMapper you will get the Facade populated with all the data from ContosoEmployeeModel, so you can use it as INavigationItem and ContosoEmployeeModel the same time, without a need to redeclare all the model properties

Comment: You're right! I can't believe I missed that point! @MatthewWatson suggested using Automapper, but I obviously dismissed it too quickly. Frustratingly, there is a bug in the Contoso model (A property can be initialised to null, but can't be set to null) that I'll need to investigate, but AutoMapper is absolutely the right answer.

Comment: Brilliantly, AutoMapper allows you to work around issues like this using ForMember to apply property-specific mapping rules. It exactly answers my question - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Resharper allows the creation of "delegating members", which copies the interface of a contained object onto the containing object and tunnels the method calls/property access through to the contained object.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html

Once you've done that, you can then extract an interface on your proxy class.

Comment: I've just downloaded the free trial, and that will certainly work for me :) Weirdly, it doesn't create them with the "new" keyword, which is a shame, so I'd have to hand-edit it anyway (but obviously much quicker!!). I think I'll do it using T4 anyway, as it will be easier to generate new versions if the Contoso models change, but thanks very much for the suggestion.